# In Hadoop can we control the number of nodes per job programatically?

Tags: hadoop

I am running a job timing analysis. I have a pre configured cluster with 8 nodes. I want to run a given job with 8 nodes, 6 nodes , 4 nodes and 2 nodes respectively and note down the corresponding run times. Is there a way i can do this programatically, i.e by using appropriate settings in the Job configuration in Java code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways. Would prefer in the same order.

1. `exclude` files can be used to not allow some of the task trackers/data nodes connect to the job tracker/ name node. Check this [faq](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_want_to_make_a_large_cluster_smaller_by_taking_out_a_bunch_of_nodes_simultaneously._How_can_this_be_done.3F). The properties to be used are `mapreduce.jobtracker.hosts.exclude.filename` and `dfs.hosts.exclude`. Note than once the files have been changed, the name node and the job tracker have to be refreshed using the `mradmin` and `dfsadmin` commands with the `refreshNodes` option and it might take some time for the cluster to settle because data blocks have to be moved from the excluded nodes.
2. Another way is to stop the task tracker on the nodes. Then the map/reduce tasks will not be scheduled on that node. But, the data will still be fetched from all the data nodes. So, the data nodes also need to be stopped. Make sure that the name node gets out of safe mode and the replication factor is also set properly (with 2 data nodes, the replication factor can't be 3).
3. A [Capacity Scheduler](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/capacity_scheduler.html) can also be used to limit the usage of a cluster by a particular job. But, when resources are free/idle then the scheduler will allocate resources beyond capacity for better utilization of the cluster. I am not sure if this can be stopped.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. I did not have admin privileges on the cluster i was testing. So finally ended up doing it on EC2 which was way more easier as i only kept adding nodes starting from 2 in increments of 2.Your answer will still be my reference for future situations.

Answer (score 0):

Well are you good with scripting ? If so play around with start  scripts of the daemons. Since this is an experimental setup, I think restarting hadoop for each experiment should be fine.

Comment: How will restarting a Hadoop help and how is it related to scripting?

Comment: Well I meant by changing slave configuration in the script. His setup was experimental, So all he needed was to change slave file programatically having said that he needs to edit the scripts.